# Firebase Web storing / recreating currentUser

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, local-storage, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to store and recreate data from currentUser using Firebase Web SDK? I do not want to store the user's email and password (which would solve this), but I would like them to stay logged in.

This is to ensure that `id_token` stays updated each time the user launches the app. (Built in React Native, though I would prefer to use the Web SDK.)

** UPDATE **

It all came down to replacing:

`import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'`

with

`import * as firebase from 'firebase/firebase-react-native'`

Now all is well and `onAuthStateChanged` works.

Comment: Answer on how this is supposed to work below. If you're having problems making this work, post the [minimal complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Firebase Authentication SDK, Users automatically stay logged in.

To resume their previous login session, [hook into the `onAuthStateChanged` event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: Thanks for your response. But when I restart the app it does not save this information -- if I add `onAuthStateChanged` it only gives me `null` (never a user)

Comment: As I commented: in that case please post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can call `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)` in [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) to get updated `idtoken`.

Comment: Thanks. `currentUser` is null upon restarting the app though.